# Nginx and AWS API Gateway with X-Forwarded-For header not showing the real IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-api-gateway

I have the following stack: `Ngnix` -> `API Gateway` -> `Lambda` (Integration Type)

On the `Nginx` configuration file, I am using the following directive: `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`

When I'm checking logs,

1. In API Gateway logs I see the load balancer IP
2. In Lambda logs I do have access to the `X-Forwarded-For` header

My question: How can I add to API Gateway Logs the `X-Forwarded-For` header with its value, or even better, replace `sourceIP` value with the one we are forwarding.